# Raspberry Pi Doesnt boot.. only shows red light when turned on

Tags: boot-issues

This problem started happening all of a sudden... I didn't damage any of the parts, but it still doesn't boot... There isn't any problem with the SD Card, since it works perfectly fine on my second pi- some help, please... Do I have to buy a new pi?

Comment: It is difficult to guess what may have happened to your Raspberry Pi without any details. What purpose did you use the Pi for? Did you connect additional hardware? Do you use a case? Was it lying (and working) somewhere untouched? Or did you do or change anything just before it stopped working? Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: No blinking green LED? That indicate it cant read the SD card, and you say "have tested it on another Pi", well then it could be the SD card holder. See for more help
https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting

Comment: Which model pi?